# How can I use sub-projects in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm trying to move onto Qt to rewrite a win32 project that has a lot of static libraries so as a preliminary test project I tried creating a subdir project following the instructions in https://www.toptal.com/qt/vital-guide-qmake. I've seen plenty of other examples, and similar questions on this site, but none of them are a bare bones example that actually works when I build it so I'm presenting this minimal example in the hope that someone can tell me what it is that I'm missing.

Here's the file structure;

```
project/
    project.pro 
    app/
        app.pro
        main.ccp
    library/
        library.pro
        mainwindow.h
        library.pri
```

Both app and library projects are simple Qt Widgets Applications, created with the New Subproject wizard. The app project has main.cpp;

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The library project has just the header file mainwindow.h defining the MainWindow class;

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {}
    ~MainWindow() {}
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here are the pro. files;

project.pro;

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
TARGET = project
SUBDIRS = app library
app.depends = library
```

app.pro;

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = app

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

include(../library/library.pri)
```

library.pro;

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = library

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    library.pri
```

Lastly, the library.pri file;

```
LIBTARGET = library
BASEDIR   = $${PWD}
INCLUDEPATH *= $${BASEDIR}/include
LIBS += -L$${DESTDIR} -llibrary
```

The point of this is to check that I can write a project in Qt where a function in one project can reference a class in another. When compiled as a single project, with main.cpp and mainwindow.h in the same project, you get the usual application window on screen with no errors so I know both main.cpp and the MainWindow class are good; compiled as-is, with the two sub-projects, I get "'mainwindow.h' file not found" on line 1, main.cpp, and "unknown type name 'MainWindow'" on line 6, main.cpp, so the library project is obviously not getting referenced properly by the app project. I'm new to Qt and have absolutely no experience with qmake, any help would be appreciated, and as I know I'm not the only person struggling with this if anyone can help get this working I'll put it up on gtihub.

Comment: I've just realized that this can also be accomplished by using "Add Library..." in the Project context menu; "Add Library...", select "Internal Library", select the project you wish to reference, click "Finish". This adds the include, library and depends path to the .pro file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use library you need to setup two things: append `INCLUDEPATH`, and `LIBS`, you can do it in pri file, and then include in `app`, if error says "file *.h not found" it means `INCLUDEPATH` is incomplete.

Here's how you can do it:

Project structure

```
project/
├── app
│   ├── app.pro
│   └── main.cpp
├── library
│   ├── library.pri
│   ├── library.pro
│   ├── mainwindow.cpp
│   ├── mainwindow.h
│   └── mainwindow.ui
└── project.pro
```

project.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    library

app.depends = library
```

library.pri

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

win32 {
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/debug
    } else {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/release
    }
} else {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD
}
LIBS += -llibrary
```

library.pro

```
QT += gui widgets

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

SOURCES += \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui
```

app.pro

```
QT += gui widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
include($$PWD/../library/library.pri)
```

QtCreator uses shadow build by default (it can be disabled on projects page), so if you build from QtCreator IDE not from shell (command line), you are likely using shadow build. In this case all build artifacts including static libraries are build outide of source directory in a separate directory named `build-${project-name}-${device-type}-${build-config}` (build-project-Desktop-Debug in our case), so `-L$$PWD` wont work, there's `OUT_PWD` for that, unfortunately for some reason it points not to pri directory but to pro directory (build-project-Desktop-Debug/app in out case) and things get a little hairier. Here's `library.pri` that works for both shadow and normal build:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

win32 {
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/debug -L$$OUT_PWD/../library/debug
    } else {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/release -L$$OUT_PWD/../library/release
    }
} else {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD -L$$OUT_PWD/../library
}
LIBS += -llibrary
```

Full source: https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/app-and-library.git

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibrary` error when I build your project! I use ubuntu os

Comment: Did you do the `LIBS += -L`  part since that is where the library folder is added?

Comment: Wonderful! I've spent the last 5 days trying to sort this out! I will admit I got all depressed for a while until I noticed your comment about disabling shadow build, serves me right for not reading the instruction manual! Thankyou very much, I've got my project working, I downloaded yours and tried that as well, which obviously works as well. Do you know, should I repost an edited version of my question or is it enough to upvote and tag this as the answer?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R you're using shadow build, I updated my answer to address this (read at the bottom please)

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with MinGW?

Comment: @BenWeston works with mingw on my machine, it may be issue with qmake, if it sees sh.exe in PATH it tries to use unix utils and some make instructions doesnt work properly with some versions of mingw (something happens to path separators), check if del_file defined as `DEL_FILE      = rm -f` (incorrect) or as `DEL_FILE      = del` (correct), remove `.qmake.stash`, remove sh.exe from PATH and run qmake again

Comment: @BenWeston I tested with mingw64 version 8.1.0, which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using mingw64 9.0.0.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: OMG I'm so sorry! This example project works fine with both msvc and mingw, I was too wrapped up in what I was doing to think properly when I posted the comment. The issue I've got is with my "next step scenario", a subdir project added to this project; any projects added to this added subdir project wont work properly. I'll ask a seperate question if I can't figure it out in another day or two.